# Saving for web is not crisp

Tags: adobe-illustrator, image-quality, save

I have a logo (compound path) in Adobe Illustrator CC (latest version). When I open the file in AI, all is good and crisp. I can zoom in and re-size whilst keep things crisp and sharp.

However when I get to Save for Web dialog and resize the artwork as png for use on the web. It all goes a little blurry!

I have the `Scale Strokes & Effects` ticked in the Transform panel.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: can you upload a screenshot of your ai window with the export settings?

Comment: When you zoom a vector object, all the curves get recalculated for that zoom level and so no matter how far in you go, what you see on the screen is the very best possible resolution for your screen. When you export to a PNG file, you are "baking in" a very specific zoom level and then when you zoom in on that, the pixels are simply enlarged rather than recalculated. This is the nature of raster images. As far as why your PNG is blurry, without seeing it, you probably have too much detail and not enough pixels. Try exporting a larger (pixel-dimension) image.

Comment: I made a [screencast](http://screencast.com/t/mksmfzZWi9) hopefully that makes things clearer.

Comment: You’re expecting a highly detailed image that is less than 50x50 px in size to be crisp? That is simply not possible. There are just not enough pixels to make the object crisp. As Yorik says, you have too much detail and too few pixels. If you tried drawing the same logo with all the details there by manually drawing one pixel at a time, you’d also soon find that it is simply not possible.

Comment: but we if make the lines thinner, it would be crisper no?

Comment: @ciwan Try it and see! :)

Comment: you do understand the difference between vector and raster, dont you?

Comment: Yep I do. I don't know how to @Vicki.

Comment: Thinner lines doesn't mean crisper lines when saved as a very tiny raster image (png, jpg, gif, etc.). Pixels can only be 1 color at a time. Your clean vector lines are not aligned perfectly to the pixels, so the pixels essentially have to decide, "Should I be blue, white, or something in between?" Those blurry pixels have picked the "something in between" color. Some fuzziness is unavoidable unless you have pixel-perfect art.